# NullPointerException when calling fragment function from different fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The Timer Setup fragment is the page layout and Timer Setting fragment is one of many settings on the Timer Setup fragment.

Here I am initializing a TimerSetting fragment warm_up_fragment, and attempting to call one of the functions in the TimerSetting fragment.

```
public class TimerSetupFragment extends Fragment {
    TimerSettingFragment warm_up_fragment;
    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer_setup, container, false);

        warm_up_fragment = TimerSettingFragment.newInstance("Warm Up", "warm_up_string", "Off", "warm_up_ms", A_TIMER_TIMES, A_TIMER_MS);

        requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .add(R.id.warm_up_fragment, warm_up_fragment, "warm_up_frag")
            .commit();

        if (condition) {
            //problem line
            warm_up_fragment.disableView();
        }

        return view;
}
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception on:

```
warm_up_fragment.disableView();
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I thought it had something to do with the fragment not being created yet, so I moved the problem line into onViewCreated(), and I'm still getting the same error.

Doing the following also does not work:

```
        if (condition) {
            if (warm_up_fragment != null) {
                warm_up_fragment.disableView();
            }
        }
```

It occurs on any line in disableView(). If I comment the first one out, the error moves to the next line.

```
public void disableView() {
    Animation up_exit = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_exit);

    hideView(confirm, null, true);
    hideView(cancel, null, true);
    hideView(edit, null, true);
    hideView(picker, up_exit, false);

    label.animate().alpha(0.38f).setDuration(400);
    value.animate().alpha(0.38f).setDuration(400);
}
```

The weird part is if I try to call the same function from inside an onCheckedChangeListener (in onCreateView in TimerSetup), and then use the switch, it executes properly:

```
timer_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                warm_up_fragment.enableView();
            } else {
                warm_up_fragment.disableView();
            }
        });
```

I know I am referencing the correct fragment since the functions execute properly in onCheckedChangeListener.

It seems the warm_up_fragment is being created, but there is a delay from when I can call functions from it. Sleeping before the function call does not work.

Been stuck on this for a while now, and other SO posts haven't helped.

Comment: I think your error occurs in this line   AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_exit); try to wrap it  wit if (getContxt != null) else lod.d(TAG,"context is null"). try it

Comment: That's the line the error shows up for, however if I comment that line out, the error moves to the next line. Every line in the function returns a null pointer exception leading me to believe the view and its elements are not being initialized. I initialize the views (confirm, cancel, edit, picker, etc) in onCreateView of the TimerSetting fragment. They are being initialized eventually because if I remove the call to disableView(), they show up on the screen and function correctly. To reply to your response, the context does return null.

Comment: where does this  'timer_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener..' written ? onViewCreated or onCreatView because i think the view is not initialized as well .

Comment: if your goal to hide show a view you can pass an argument to the fragment or use sharedpreferances

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s are asynchronous by default, so your `TimerSettingFragment` will not have been through its initial lifecycle methods yet when you try to use it there immediately after the `commit()`. If you really need that transacted immediately, you can use a method which forces that, like [`commitNow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commitNow()), for example.

Comment: I really should've mentioned that you should avoid doing that, however, if you can. As I reread your code here, it would be trivial to put that `condition` as an argument on the `TimerSettingFragment` instead, and then let it handle the check and `disableView()` call itself internally.

Comment: Yes I've moved the condition to inside the TimerSettingFragment. I was hoping to avoid that since there is one TimerSettingFragment for about 15 settings and wanted to avoid hardcoding something like `if (fragment_name).equals("Warm Up"))` inside the TimerSettingFragment. However that seems to be the easy fix.

Comment: What I like to do is NEVER call an `Android Lifecycle` class Activity/Fragment/DialogFragment function from outside of its own class. All communication, is done through observers/callbacks. The `Android Lifecycle` class needs to manage its own state 100%. It and only it should be messing with its views.

Comment: This is also something you could pass into a bundle, along with your other 15 settings, as such when the Fragment retrieves it, the fragment can disable the view. If this results in a non clean solution you could always abstract it. `TimerSettingFragment` is the base class and `WarmUpTimerSettingFragment` extends it and overrides `OnResume` and sets the desired views to be disabled.